# so i need help completing the java doc comments

Tags: java

so this is part of the code. as you can see i have no idea what to put in the comments. i'm still new to programming and suck at it. so i kinda need a bit of help. what should i put in them. trust me i asked my professor for help all she said is that shes the customer and has no idea how to help.

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (testOne != other.testOne)
        return false;
    if (testTwo != other.testTwo)
        return false;
    return true;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [name=" + name + ", testOne=" + testOne + ", testTwo=" + testTwo + "]";
}
}
```

so for the bottom comment it would look like this?

```
     /**
      * @returns a string representation of Students name, testOne, and testTwo
      */
     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", testOne=" + testOne + ", testTwo=" + testTwo + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: put the purpose of method in comment. You can check the documentation comments in existing java classes e.g. **Object.java**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, the proper way to structure a Javadoc comment is like this:

```
/**
 * ...
 */
```

When commenting on a function, the format is usually similar to this:

```
/**
 * This is a description of the function and what it does.
 * @param argument1 this is a description of a parameter
 * @param argument2 this is a description of a second parameter
 * @return this is a description of what the function returns
 */
 public boolean myFunction(argument1, argument2){
     ...
```

You can read more about Javadoc syntax [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java Doc usually is written to explain about the purpose of class or method.
In case of method, the javadoc is used to firstly mention what the method does in plain english. In addtion to this we mention parameter to the method, date when the method was wrote,author name, exception the method throws (if any) and return of the method (if any).
Java doc is written above method declaration using javadoc comment which is

```
/**
* JavaDoc comment goes here
* @param <paramName>
* @author Mr XYZ
* @throws Exception
*/
public void methodName(Datatype paramName) throws Exception{
  //Method body
}
```

For mentioning parameter we use @param tag, for exception we use @throws, for author of method we use @author , for date we use @since or @date and for return we use @return

You can use html tags like `<p> , <b> , <i>, <blockquote>, <pre>,<em>` in java doc comment to format it and make it more readable and better look.